# A concurrency exception has occurred - Api call, .net core, jsonpatch document update

Tags: c#, reactjs, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core

Getting this exception when one of end point of api gets call, on data update.

[image]

Also from client end there are two same calls are happening at a same time. Got confused how to fix it. Here is the screenshot

[image]

When multiple user perform the update exception occurs, wanted to get rid of this exception

Comment: That's expected behavior when multiple users attempt to update the same rowversion-enabled record starting with stale information: if all of the updates were applied then information would be lost. Read up on [Handling Concurrency Conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency). Microsoft has been telling us for twenty+ years that the `timestamp` data type synonym is deprecated in SQL Server and that we should be using `rowversion` instead, but then they go ahead and create the `[Timestamp]` attribute in Entity Framework... go figure!

Comment: Just a note: there seem to be three calls with the same ID in the second screenshot

Comment: Hello @MikeSzyndel, the third call is get call to get the updated entity.

Answer (score 0):

> Getting this exception when one of end point of api gets call, on data
> update.

Based on your error descriptions it seems that while multiple trying to manipulate the same data or table you are having this issue which technically called as [concurrency conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency?view=aspnetcore-7.0#concurrency-conflicts)

Generally [concurrency conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency?view=aspnetcore-7.0#concurrency-conflicts) occurs when one user displays an entity's data in order to edit it, and then another user updates the same entity's data before the first user's change is written to the database.

> When multiple user perform the update exception occurs, wanted to get
> rid of this exception.

A most handy and popular way to resolve concurrency conflilcts is to merge the pending changes with the new values in the database. To overcome concurrency issue numerous measures can be taken. For instance we can consider following actions:

1. [Isolation level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations#using-isolation-levels-for-concurrency-control) can be implement,
2. We Can [keep track of which property a user has modified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency?view=aspnetcore-7.0#add-a-tracking-property)
3. [Can Use Locking Mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency?view=aspnetcore-7.0#pessimistic-concurrency-locking)

Either of above way could be identical for your to handle the scenario you have. You could [check the official sample here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency?view=aspnetcore-7.0#get-the-code)

**Note:**

In addition to this, as your scenario can be considered as [Optimistic Concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency?view=aspnetcore-7.0#optimistic-concurrency) where could introduce a RowVersion of type Timestamp to keep tracking  where DbConcurrencyException might happend. You can [have a look our official document for details implemntation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency?view=aspnetcore-7.0#detecting-concurrency-conflicts).